# Any way to reduce the logging level of SQL Audit?

Tags: audit

I set up SQL Audit according to STIG compliance using exactly the recommendations given by the compliance documents. The problem is that after doing so my server is generating roughly 5GB of Audit logs an hour.  I looked around but I see no way to reduce the logging level of the audit logs or do anything that will enable me to not take up so much space. I have to enable this type of logging across 11 servers and I can't justify that amount of space usage for this. Is there a setting I'm missing? Is this amount of space consumption normal even?